# All-In-One-SEO plugin sitemap is blank

Tags: seo, googlebot, sitemap, xml-sitemap, cdn

recently I was working on a project and needed to upload the sitemap to Google search console, I am using All-in-One-SEO plugin for generating sitemap and SEO of this site.

However when I go to the sitemap page, it is fully blank, I read the plugin's own guide on why it can be blank but it did not help much and I couldn't fix it even after reinstalling the plugin and reconfiguring it.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem was with the CDN, beside the SEO plugin I usually install a optimization plugin, Redis plugin and Wordfence and always configure CDN the first day.

Since XML and XSL files were being cached by CDN, page was throwing CORS error and avoiding these contents to load thus leading to a blank page. I excluded XML and XSL files form CDN within my CDN plugin and also purged cache on the website as well as the CDN and everything went back to normal.

I am sharing this here, maybe someone else faces the same issue and this might help. If the page is blank first please click on F12 and then go to network tab to see if CORS issue is happening and if it is coming from your CDN, in those cases this solution might help

Comment: What CDN were you using? I stopped using All-in-One when it became "AIOSEO". Classic "paved paradise, and put up a parking lot".

Comment: BunnyCDN for CDN. For the SEO, I sometimes also use Yoast but generally decreased using it cause many of the things I needed from it were in premium. Rank Math is new but seems promising too, I might go with that in future more

Comment: Rank Math is what I've switched most of my sites over to.